# "We were unable to load Disqus." with jekyll's default minima theme

Tags: javascript, github, jekyll, github-pages, disqus

When setting up [my personal blog](https://sunqingyao.github.io/miscellaneous/2017/01/12/my-first-blog-post/) with jekyll, I found that I cannot get the comments section shown. It kept telling me:

> We were unable to load Disqus. If you are a moderator please see our
>   troubleshooting guide.

Relevant code: <sub>(For the complete code, please visit my repo: https://github.com/sunqingyao/sunqingyao.github.io)</sub>

> _config.yml

```
disqus:
  shortname: sled-dog
```

> _layouts/post.html

```
{% if site.disqus.shortname %}
  {% include disqus_comments.html %}
{% endif %}
```

> disqus_comments.html

```
{% if page.comments != false and jekyll.environment == "production" %}

  <div id="disqus_thread"></div>
  <script>
    var disqus_config = function () {
      this.page.url = '{{ page.url | absolute_url }}';
      this.page.identifier = '{{ page.url | absolute_url }}';
    };
    (function() {
      var d = document, s = d.createElement('script');
      s.src = 'https://{{ site.disqus.shortname }}.disqus.com/embed.js';
      s.setAttribute('data-timestamp', +new Date());
      (d.head || d.body).appendChild(s);
    })();
  </script>
  <noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the <a href="https://disqus.com/?ref_noscript" rel="nofollow">comments powered by Disqus.</a></noscript>
{% endif %}
```

I've read through the [troubleshooting guide](https://docs.disqus.com/help/83/) several times and checked every possible situation, but the comments are still not appearing.

A few things to note:

1. I'm using **minima**, jekyll's default theme, and following its [document](https://github.com/jekyll/minima#enabling-comments-via-disqus).
2. I've registered a Disqus account and verified email address.
3. My website shortname is `sled-dog`.
4. `github.io` has been added to "Trusted Domains".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is an error in the `this.page.identifier` variable.

It should contain the page's unique identifier, but it is currently setting the page's url: `this.page.identifier = '{{ page.url | absolute_url }}';`

You should change it to:

```
this.page.identifier = {{ site.disqus.shortname }}';
```

再见

- Update

Surround `var disqus_config` with comment tags: `/* var disqus_config = ...*/`.

Comment: 谢谢你！However, it's still not working: https://sunqingyao.github.io/miscellaneous/2017/01/12/my-first-blog-post/ :( Can you see the comments section in your browser? I suspect there might be some problems with my network configuration. You know, we have [GFW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Firewall) in China...

Comment: Strange, I have the same code as yours (https://github.com/marcanuy/simpleit.rocks/blob/master/_includes/disqus.html), the only difference is the var disqus=config surrounded by comment tags: ` /*
    var disqus_config = ...*/`.

Comment: After commenting out the `var disqus_config` part, everything works like magic! I can't tell the reason under the hood, but it just works...

Comment: Please edit your answer, and I'll accept it immediately :)

Comment: In my case, `this.page.identifier` modification was enough: csonuryilmaz.github.io   Thanks @marcanuy

Comment: I think this should not work. the identifier should be unique, in this case it will be the same for all pages.

Comment: `this.page.identifier` needs to have a unique id per disqus comments page. Setting it to shortname will cause overlapping comment sections if you have more than 1 pages where disqus comments are added on your page. I'm puzzled as to why this answer has so many likes.

Comment: How is this the right answer? The page.identifier should be unique to the each post, setting it to the shortname is probably collapsing all the comments in a single thread.

Answer (score 14):

I'm surprised that the best answer is to disable discus.config.

If you have issues to enable disqus on your website with default jekyll theme, please check parameters.

**_config.yml** should include:

`disqus:
    shortname: test-shortname`

`url: http://yourwebsite.com`

**JEKYLL_ENV** should be set to "production"

`export JEKYLL_ENV=production`

That's all you need. Good luck.

Comment: This is the correct answer, backed up by the official Minima [README](https://github.com/jekyll/minima).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at original post by @nazlok, i had a similar issue after googling around, I found out the disqus short_name is not the same as the disqus account name. In fact it is site-specific.

From what I see in your *_config.yml* , your `short_name: sled-dog` could be your 'disqus account name'.

Confirm that you have the correct short_name for your site. See [what-is-a-shortname](https://help.disqus.com/en/articles/1717111-what-s-a-shortname) on how to access the short_name.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using a relative URL for `this.page.url` but it should be an absolute URL,

```
{{ page.url | absolute_url }}
```